# facebook GET user's friends details failed on unity facebook sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I tried to get the user's friends details on Unity by calling FB.API :

```
public string ApiQuery = "me/friends";
public void CallFBAPI()
{
  FB.API(ApiQuery, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, Callback);
}
```

I logged in by calling :

```
FB.Login("basic_info,user_friends,email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
```

I tried many times changing the permissions by combining all of them or just one of them but everytime I try to get the friends list, the response always shows "404: Bad response"

I am not sure whether this is bug from the Unity Facebook SDK itself (tried to use different versions such as 5.0.3, 5.0.2) or I am doing wrong with the code to call the user's friends details. Could somebody please help me with this issues?

Thanks much!

Comment: what platform you are using ?

Comment: I am using Android platform. I was even trying to run it on the Unity editor but still got the same result. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you should run it on android device. I used it with iOS.The work on device but shows error on unity editor.

Comment: May I know what fb permissions did you set for the login call method?